Display images in listview in columns
I'm looking for how to devise my listview by rows. Now I'm having a listview with images who displays in rows but I want to do Grid in this listview to diplay images by columns.
My xaml
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lstImagesView" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Width="200" Source="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

images in row
Thanks for help
